# Looking for a Racktables Tutorial or how to create Racks

Tags: networking

How do I create Racks in [Racktables](http://racktables.org/)? I've created my physical and virtual objects, routers, and switches. Added my locations and rows(?) but can figure out how to create Racks and then add objects to the racks. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to navigate to the row and then add the rack.
Mainpage -> Rackspace -> Row -> Add Rack

See here in the demo:
View the row: http://demo.racktables.org/index.php?page=row&tab=default&row_id=966
There is a button to add a new rack (http://demo.racktables.org/index.php?page=row&tab=newrack&row_id=966)